# EdDSA point encoding difference between documentation and implementation

Tags: implementation, eddsa

The RFC 8032 describes the point encoding like this :

> A curve point (x,y), with coordinates in the range 0 <= x,y < p, is
> coded as follows.  First, encode the y-coordinate as a little-endian
> string of 32 octets.  The most significant bit of the final octet is
> always zero.  To form the encoding of the point, copy the least
> significant bit of the x-coordinate to the most significant bit of
> the final octet.

And implements it like this :

```
def point_compress(P):
    zinv = modp_inv(P[2])
    x = P[0] * zinv % p
    y = P[1] * zinv % p
    return int.to_bytes(y | ((x & 1) << 255), 32, "little")
```

Could you explain the meaning of the word "copy" in this sentence "copy the least significant bit of the x-coordinate to the most significant bit of the final octet" ? Why isn't the bit copied in the code ? Why is it just a bitwise OR ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could you explain the meaning of the word "copy" in this sentence "copy the least significant bit of the x-coordinate to the most significant bit of the final octet" ? Why isn't the bit copied in the code ? Why is it just a bitwise OR ?

First of all note that;

> # Points are represented as tuples (X, Y, Z, T) of extended
> # coordinates, with x = X/Z, y = Y/Z, x*y = T/Z

So the `zinv` comes from there and

> ```
> x = P[0] * zinv % p
> y = P[1] * zinv % p
> ```

Uses to find `x` and `y`

Now the last line does what the RFC describes in a simple way.

> `int.to_bytes(y | ((x & 1) << 255), 32, "little")`

The code is just a demonstration of the result. In your programming environment, you can use copy bit by bit, and it will be way slower.

A bitwise or operation is much faster than bit by bit copy. Also, as you can see there are no range check or `if` to check boundaries. Since the formula is fixed you can use whatever optimization is needed as longs as your code doesn't leak information.

Final note: you restrict yourself with the bit-by-bit copy. Doesn't the result copy the values into the return value?

Comment: if the most significant bit is 1 and the least significant bit of x is 0, the resulting bit will be 1. not 0 as I expected while reading the word "copy"

Comment: Because `The most significant bit of the final octet is always zero.`

Comment: is the "final octet" the most significant one ?

Comment: Does the Little Endian explain this?